# make C# method wait for JS event to happen

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

## Intro

I'm programming a project where C# and JavaScript code need to work together, so I decided to use [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) as it guarantees the latest JS features (in contrast with WebView).

## The Goal

Now I need to create an **async C# method** which would call an **async JS function** and then **wait for it to finish**. The problem is that JavaScript doesn't have anything like the `await` keyword, so everything is defined in terms of *events*.

This is what the Javascript code looks like:

```
var name1 = "A";
var name2 = "B";

library.renameObject("A","B");
library.onrename = function(from, to){
  if(from === "A"){
    //let C# know
  }
}
```

And the C# code should ideally be something like this:

```
class FooObject
{
  string Name;
  async Task Rename(string newName)
  {
    await mainFrame.EvaluateScriptAsync(@"
      //The JS code
    ");
    Name = newName;
  }
}
```

## The Problem

At first I thought using a task/promise would do the job, but after some testing I found out that it's impossible to pass objects between JS and C#.

This means that when I tried to pass `TaskCompletionSource` to an `IJavascriptCallback`, I got

> System.NotSupportedException: Complex types cannot be serialized to Cef lists

Then I tried to return a `Promise` from the JavaScript code, but in C# I always got `null`.

---

## A Bad Solution

I'm aware that using reflection, proxies and `Dictionary<int, WeakRef<object>>` I could provide an interface, so that any C# object could be accessed from JavaScript in a way that would be indistinguishable from using an actual JS object. The approach would be:

1. save (a weakref to) the C# object in the dictionary under a unique key
2. using `Reflection` create methods that take the unique key as an argument and allow reading fields and calling methods of the object
3. expose these methods to JavaScript using `RegisterJsObject`
4. create a `Proxy` that would mimic an ordinary JS object and call the exposed C# methods in the background.

The bad news with this solution is that in JavaScript there are no destructors/finalizers, so I have no control over the V8 GC. This means the C# objects would stay there forever (memory leak) or get collected by the .Net GC too early (null pointer exception).

Comment: I've only used CEF3 not CEFSharp, but can you just store the data in JS then send an event to C# letting it know that the data is available to fetch?  Or send the data as a string to parse and object-ify?

Comment: Sending an event to C# is a good idea. However if the JavaScript code failed somehow, I'd have a method waiting forever.

Comment: On the C# side you split your code into 2 parts - part 1 starts an action then returns immediately without waiting.  On completion you get an event.  In C# you set flag(s) that the action is in progress, maybe with the time it started and a sequence ID.  If the part 2 never gets called after x seconds you know it probably failed.

Comment: @DaveS The problem is that it's a non-static method. And storing the instances in a dictionary is ugly at least. At most it's breaking my good code by exposing internal-stuff methods as public.

Comment: *Don't* use `async void`, that's only for event handlers. An `async void` method *can't* be awaited, it's essentially a fire-and-forget method

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry, that was a typo :) Of course I need to await it later.

Comment: "Your best bet would be to bind an object and have the JS function callback to the bound object when done" (from https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2188)