# Event to task – searching for the elegant way

Tags: c#, events, task, extension-methods, c#-7.0

### Intro

In my code there is a lot of places where I need to wait until an event fires before proceeding. Tasks (combined with `await`) are ideal for this, so I thought I'd make an extension method for `EventHandler<T>` that would simplify this kind of situation.

I need something like this pseudocode:

```
event EventHandler<int> AllFinished;

async Task<int> DoThings()
{
    InitiateAnAction();
    var n = await /* wait for AllFinished to fire */;
    return n;
}
```

### Try #1

My first idea was that I'd implement an explicit cast from `EventHandler` to `Task` but I found out that [operators cannot be overloaded with extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306614/extension-method-and-explicit-casting). If it had worked, it would have looked like this:

```
var n = await (Task)AllFinished;
```

.

### Try #2

My second attempt was to use an ordinary extension method. This is the code I used:

```
public static Task<(object sender, T args)> Once<T>(this EventHandler<T> e)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<(object, T)>();
    EventHandler<T> d = null;

    d = delegate (object sender, T args)
    {
        tcs.SetResult( (sender, args) );
        e -= d;
    };

    e += d;
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

However I found out that [events can't be passed as arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560258/how-to-pass-an-event-to-a-method), so the `e += d` and `e -= d` didn't do anything (they didn't even throw an error). If it had worked, it would have been used like this:

```
var (sender, number) = await AllFinished.Once();
```

.

### Question

Is there an elegant way of awaiting events? I'd prefer an one-liner as in my two previous attempts:

```
var n = await (Task)AllFinished;
var (sender, number) = await AllFinished.Once();
```

If it's possible, please avoid passing event's name as a string. This approach would make it impossible to use the IntelliSense rename feature, which could break my code when I forget about it.

.

### Why do I need this?

If you think that waiting for events inside methods is a result of a bad design, you can dive into my [original Cef-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44463255/make-c-sharp-method-wait-for-js-event-to-happen) and post a better solution there.

Comment: If answers in duplicate question does not satisfy you - you may consider looking at Rx (reactive extensions). They have Observable.FromEvent and that observable can be awaited just like Task.

Comment: Rx allows you to *process* event streams using LINQ operators as if they were data. It's *very* useful for UIs, eg. to debounce clicks, respond to specific series of events, throttling. It's a lot more than just awaiting an event